# When to use “en tant que” and “comme”?

Tags: usage, prépositions

Usually when using computers I see sentences like:

> Executer en tant qu'administrateur

And then I hear or read sentences like:

> travailler comme indépendant

Are there any instances when "en tant que" and "comme" can be interchanged ?

Is it correct to say:

> travailler en tant qu'indépendant

or

> Exécuter comme administrateur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, I'd say that there is a subtle notion of temporality in the sentence.

> Exécuter en tant qu'administrateur

Means that you are **temporarily** considered as Administrator, just to execute an action. Whereas

> Travailler comme administrateur

Means that you work as an administrator full-time, there is nothing temporary in this.